# python print format and line breaking

Tags: python

I have this loop:

```
for n in range(101):
    money_growth = A*(1 + p/100)**n
    print "%d Euro after %3d year[s] with \
    interest of %0.2f will be %0.2f" %(A, n, p, money_growth)
```

I break the line with \  in front of print statement but it will extra tab due to the loop intention:

```
00 year[s] with     interest of 0.05
```

the only solution I found was doing t this way:

```
    for n in range(101):
        money_growth = A*(1 + p/100)**n
        print "%d Euro after %3d year[s] with \
    interest of %0.2f will be %0.2f" %(A, n, p, money_growth)
```

but It destroy the readability somehow
is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use implicit string concatenation by breaking the string as:

```
for n in range(101):
    money_growth = A*(1 + p/100)**n
    print "%d Euro after %3d year[s] with" \
    "interest of %0.2f will be %0.2f" %(A, n, p, money_growth)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and print with brackets () for Python 3 compitability. We could also use indexes if we want to repeat a string.

```
A,p,n = 1,1,1

string = "{} Euro after {:>3} year[s] with interest of {} will be {:.2f}"
#string = "{0} Euro after {1:>3} year[s] with interest of {2} will be {3:.2f}"

for n in range(101):
    money_growth = A*(1 + p/100)**n
    print(string.format(A, n, p, money_growth))
```

**or:** we could use list comprehension and join the list print items with row breaks.

```
A,p,n = 1,1,1
string = "{} Euro after {:>3} year[s] with interest of {} will be {:.2f}"
output = [string.format(A, n, p, A*(1 + p/100)**n) for n in range(101)]
print('\n'.join(output))
```

This is very powerful way to print strings, the options are endless and I always learn something new when I look through the docs. For instance you can use this to convert numbers to Hex format.

```
rgb = (0,100,200)
string = "#"+"{:02x}"*3
print(string.format(*rgb))
```

Returns:

```
#0064c8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(101):
    money_growth = A*(1 + p/100)**n
    print("{:d} {} {:3d} {} {} {:.2f} {} {:.2f}".format(
        A, "Euro after", n, "years[s]","with interest of", p, "will be", money_growth
    ))
```

A good way to avoid this is to use string formatting function. You can format it in chain fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Place the format string outside your loop:

```
s = "%d Euro after %3d year[s] with interest of %0.2f will be %0.2f"
for n in range(101):
   money_growth = A*(1 + p/100)**n
   print s % (A,n,p,money_growth)
```